# JSONParsingException is valid only for START_OBJECT parser state

Tags: java, json

When running a class that is supposed to read a JSON array of objects, I am getting the following error.

**Exception in thread "main" javax.json.stream.JsonParsingException: JsonParser#getObject() or JsonParser#getObjectStream() is valid only for START_OBJECT parser state. But current parser state is START_ARRAY
at org.glassfish.json.JsonReaderImpl.readObject(JsonReaderImpl.java:114)
at AIProject.WordGrabber.(WordGrabber.java:28)**

I know the issue is that our JSON starts as an array, and we are starting looking at Objects first.  I have been unable to find a way to get the code to run looking at an array of objects.  The JSON is a series of single word Markove chains.  Below is the Class that is kicking the error.

```
import java.util.Random;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonReader;
import javax.json.JsonValue;

public class WordGrabber {
    File jsonIF ;
    InputStream is;
    JsonReader reader;
    JsonObject jsonObj;
    
    //Constructor
    public WordGrabber() {
        try {
            jsonIF = new File("data/MarkovChain.json");
            is = new FileInputStream(jsonIF);
            reader = Json.createReader(is);
            jsonObj = reader.readObject();
            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("JSon Missing");
        }
        
    }
    
    //This will return a random word from the JSon
    public String readArray(String st) {
        int rnd;
        JsonArray arrObj = jsonObj.getJsonArray(st);
        ArrayList<String> listWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (JsonValue value : arrObj) {
            listWords.add(value.toString());
        }
        rnd = new Random().nextInt(listWords.size());
        return listWords.get(rnd);
    }
}
```

And this is a sample of the JSon t is supposed to be traversing.

```
[{"wasted;": ["I", "dish", "carelessly", "voice:"]},
{"villagers": [",", "by", "rendered", "neighbouring"]}, 
{"susceptible": [".", "of", "rendered", "despised"]}, {"stir": 
[".", "despised", "paroxysms", "carelessly"]}, {"brightly": 
["on", "rendered", "dish", "carelessly"]}, {"finished;": 
["in", "rendered", "dish", "voice:"]}, {"arrest": ["a", 
"rendered", "neighbouring", "voice:"]}, {"supreme": 
["delight", "and", "rendered", "criminal"]}, {"facility": 
["of", "rendered", "neighbouring", "voice:"]}, {"WORK": ["To", 
"rendered", "dish", "carelessly"]}, {"followers": ["of", 
"rendered", "neighbouring", "voice:"]}, {"worn": ["on", 
"into", "coats", "when"]}, {"services": [".", "towards", 
"rendered", "carelessly"]}, {"pursuit": [".", ",", "of", 
"among"]}, {"guidance": ["of", "rendered", "neighbouring", 
"voice:"]}, {"Donations": ["to", "are", "rendered", "dish"]}, 
{"need": ["to", "not", "of", "no"]}, {"adhesive": ["from", 
"on", "rendered", "dish"]}, {"strong": ["enough", "north", 
"a", "northerly"]}, {"supplication": ["to", "rendered", 
"dish", "carelessly"]}, {"meadows": ["of", "and", "rendered", 
"despised"]}, {"Caroline": ["Beaufort", "became", "dish", 
"carelessly"]}, {"pouring": ["in", "down", "rendered", 
"criminal"]}, {"quenched": ["her", "in", "rendered", 
"carelessly"]}, {"chemical": ["instruments", "apparatus", 
"instrument", "chilled"]}, {"This": ["was", "idea", "is", 
"letter"]}, {"sorry": ["chemist", ".", "that", "massacred"]}, 
{"_wives": [",", "rendered", "criminal", "carelessly"]}, 
{"protracted": ["my", "rendered", "dish", "carelessly"]}, 
{"lovedst": [".", "despised", "paroxysms", "carelessly"]}, 
{"whilst": ["I", "M", "those", "my"]}, {"displays": 
["unbounded", "rendered", "dish", "voice:"]}, {"motionless": 
[",", "for", ".", "and"]}, {"benevolent": ["countenance", 
"and", "pleasure", "mind"]}, {"raved": ["incessantly", 
"rendered", "dish", "carelessly"]}, {"woods;": ["the", 
"rendered", "case;", "paroxysms"]}, {"itch": ["was", "up", 
"rendered", "neighbouring"]}, {"Uri": [",", "rendered", 
"criminal", "carelessly"]}, {"test": ["the", "his", 
"rendered", "case;"]},
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message says (in effect) that you are trying to read a JSON object, but it has found a JSON array.

Given that your input is an array, you should be using

```
        jsonArray = reader.readArray();
```

instead of

```
        jsonObj = reader.readObject();
```

in the constructor.  Then make appropriate adjustments elsewhere.

---

> I have been unable to find a way to get the code to run looking at an array of objects.

I recommend reading the [javadocs](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/package-summary.html) for `javax.json` to help you understand how out how to use the API.

For instance, the [javadoc](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/JsonReader.html#readObject--) for the `readObject` method tells you that it throws an `JsonParsingException` if a JSON object cannot be read.  And a JSON array is not a JSON object.

The [javadoc](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/json/JsonReader.html#readArray--) for `readArray` is just a few screen-inches above or below.  (Below in the version I am looking at ...)